# How to open multiple javascript pop ups at the same time?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, popup, popupwindow

Im trying to open multiple pop ups at the same time. I tried using loops, but it didnt work.I don't understand why this doesn't work. Is there a better way to do this? My code:

js:

```
function myFunction() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=400, height=200");

                }
  }
```

html:

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second argument to `window.open()` must be unique for it to open a new window or must be set to `"_blank"`.

From the [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for `window.open()`:

> ```
> var windowObjectReference = window.open(strUrl, strWindowName, [strWindowFeatures]);
> ```
>
> If a window with the name `strWindowName` already exists, then `strUrl` is
>   loaded into the existing window. In this case the return value of the
>   method is the existing window and `strWindowFeatures` is ignored.
>   Providing an empty string for `strUrl` is a way to get a reference to an
>   open window by its name without changing the window's location. To
>   open a new window on every call of `window.open()`, use the special
>   value `"_blank"` for `strWindowName`.

---

Note: most browsers these days have popup blockers built in.  Those popup blockers will generally allow one new window to be opened when it is the direct result of a mouse click, but they may impose limits if the code is trying to open lots of windows.  This popup blocker behavior is not per some specification so it likely varies in detailed implementation from browser to browser.